# Check if ISO String date is between two dates

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to check if the middle date is between the right and left date, how can I accomplish this in Javascript, they are an `ISO String`.

```
From 2021-01-30T05:00:00.000Z <-> Date 2021-01-31T22:18:46Z <-> To 2021-01-31T05:00:00.000Z
```

How can I verify **`2021-01-31T22:18:46Z`** is between `2021-01-30T05:00:00.000Z` and `2021-01-31T05:00:00.000Z`

Comment: If the timestamp strings were always the same width and format, you could just use a regular inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea is we just need to compare `Date` only.

However, if you use `.moment` or `new Date()` to parse the `date-time UTC`, you will recognize an interesting that

```
moment("2021-01-31T22:18:46Z").format("YYYY-MM-DD") // "2021-02-01"
new Date("2021-01-31T22:18:46Z") // Mon Feb 01 2021 05:18:46 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time)
```

So if the `compareDate` like `2021-01-31T05:00:00.000Z`, then you will get the expected result.

```js
const fromDate = moment("2021-01-30T05:00:00.000Z").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
const conpareDate = moment("2021-01-31T05:00:00.000Z").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
const toDate = moment("2021-01-31T05:00:00.000Z").format("YYYY-MM-DD");

console.log({fromDate, conpareDate, toDate});
console.log(moment(conpareDate).isBetween(fromDate, toDate, undefined, '(]'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you still want to compare exactly the date, you can achieve it in this way (But to be honest, It's not recommended).

```js
const fromDate = '2021-01-30T05:00:00.000Z'.split('-');
const conpareDate = '2021-01-31T22:18:46Z'.split('-');
const toDate = '2021-01-31T05:00:00.000Z'.split('-');

const partStringToInt = (str) => parseInt(str, 10);
const compareBetween = (a, b, c) => partStringToInt(a) <= partStringToInt(b) && partStringToInt(b) <= partStringToInt(c);

const result = compareBetween(fromDate[0], conpareDate[0], toDate[0]) // Year
&& compareBetween(fromDate[1], conpareDate[1], toDate[1]) // Month
&& compareBetween(fromDate[2].substring(0, 2), conpareDate[2].substring(0, 2), toDate[2].substring(0, 2)); // Day
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Two easy options...

[Compare the date strings lexicographically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
const From = "2021-01-30T05:00:00.000Z"
const date = "2021-01-31T22:18:46Z"
const To   = "2021-01-31T05:00:00.000Z"

if (From.localeCompare(date) <= 0 && To.localeCompare(date) >= 0) {
  console.log("Date is in range")
} else {
  console.log("Date is not in range")
}
```

or parse the date strings as `Date` instances or timestamps and compare them numerically

```js
const From = new Date("2021-01-30T05:00:00.000Z")
const date = new Date("2021-01-31T22:18:46Z")
const To   = new Date("2021-01-31T05:00:00.000Z")

if (From <= date && To >= date) {
  console.log("Date is in range")
} else {
  console.log("Date is not in range")
}
```

---

Note: If you're using Typescript, it doesn't like comparing `Date` instances numerically. Compare [`Date.prototype.valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) or [`Date.prototype.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) instead

Comment: Thanks! But doesnt seem to work for `From 2021-01-30T05:00:00.000Z <-> Closed 2021-01-31T05:57:02Z <-> To 2021-01-31T05:00:00.000Z`

Comment: @JohnnyBiy works for me. What did you expect the result to be? As far as I can tell, `Closed` is out of range since 5:57am is **after** 5:00am for the same day

Comment: Oh then. How can I set the From and To date to midnight? So that it's in range

Comment: @JohnnyBiy I don't understand your question. If you want to change the `From` and `To` dates / times, just change them

Answer (score 0):

```
function getElapsedMS(strOfD1, strOfD2) {
var d1 = new Date(strOfD1);
var d2 = new Date(strOfD2);
return d1-d2;
}

var d2d1 = getElapsedMS("2021-01-31T22:18:46Z", "2021-01-30T05:00:00.000Z");
var d2d3 = getElapsedMS("2021-01-31T22:18:46Z", "2021-01-31T05:00:00.000Z");
if (d2d1 * d2d3 < 0) { // can have more consideration to avoid overflow
//d2 is between d1 and d3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Unix timestamp

Each date can be represented as `milliseconds since epoch`, so we can convert each date to milliseconds and compare whether one date is after another or not.

Example:

```js
const dateA = new Date("2021-01-30T05:00:00.000Z");
const dateB = new Date("2021-01-31T05:00:00.000Z");

const dateC = new Date("2021-01-31T22:18:46Z");

// We use getTime() method to get the date as milliseconds since epoch
const isDateCBetweenAandB = dateA.getTime() <= dateC.getTime() && dateC.getTime() <= dateB.getTime();

console.log(isDateCBetweenAandB);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can compare its unix timestamp try it:

```
Date.parse('2021-01-31T22:18:46Z');
```

Comment: Then I get date object?